# IOS actionsheet button selection not working properly

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

Hi I am developing small IOS application in which I am using actionsheet. So my problem is like this when I clicked outside the actionsheet it is closing my actionsheet it  is calling `- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` method even though I am not clicking any button of actionsheet. It is returning lastindexof action sheet button. So how to avoid this. Any solution? I tried with `-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)action didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`
  But still same result.

Answer (score 0):

I write the time picker by my self instead UIActionSheet in iOS8:

```
date = [NSDate date];

timePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];
timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
timePicker.hidden = NO;
timePicker.date = date;

displayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[displayFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[displayFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM月dd日 EEE HH:mm"];

formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

startDisplayTimeString = [displayFormatter stringFromDate:timePicker.date];
startTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:timePicker.date];

NSTimeInterval interval = 24*60*60*1;
NSDate *endDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval];
endDisplayTimeString = [displayFormatter stringFromDate:endDate];
endTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:endDate];

[_startTimeLabel setText:startDisplayTimeString];
[_endTimeLabel setText:endDisplayTimeString];

[pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64)];
pickerToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelBtnPressed:)];

[cancelBtn setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:68.0/255.0 blue:142.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *titleButton;

float pickerMarginHeight = 168;


titleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: nil action: nil];

[titleButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:68.0/255.0 blue:142.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                     nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(setTimePicker)];

[doneBtn setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:68.0/255.0 blue:142.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                 nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSArray *itemArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:cancelBtn, flexSpace, titleButton, flexSpace, doneBtn, nil];

[pickerToolbar setItems:itemArray animated:YES];

if(iPad){

    [pickerToolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 216);
    UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [popoverView addSubview:timePicker];
    [popoverView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, pickerMarginHeight, 320, 216) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

}else{

    timeBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT-300, 320, 246)];
    [timeBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:240/255.0 blue:240/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    [timeBackgroundView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [timeBackgroundView addSubview:timePicker];

    [self.view addSubview:timeBackgroundView];}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you tap outside of the UIActionSheet, UIKit performs the same action as if you had tapped the cancel button.  The `buttonIndex` that is sent in `- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` is the cancel button index.  There isn't a way to  know if the user tapped outside of your UIActionSheet, by default.  If you want this functionality you will have to code your own custom action sheet or handle the outside tap as a cancel tap.